# get QLineEdit value inside QTableWidget in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

So this time i just want to know how to get a value of QLineEdit inside the QTableWidget.

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hawc.png), and i've got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T78ML.png).

I know how to get value from QComboBox inside of QTableWidget, and it's work using `class.object.cellWidget(int, int).currentText()`.

But when I try to use `class.object.cellWidget(int, int).text()` for get QLineEdit value, it's return error look like the image, and i can't get the value. i have no idea about qobject_cast like [this link said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947300/retrieve-value-of-qtablewidget-cells-which-are-qlineedit-widgets). and i still don't understand how to using delegate. i think it will be better if someone can fix my coding, or give me a nice reference with example about this error, or give me explanation how to use delegate in QTableWidget or give me a nice reference. oh also it will be better if the example is within python because i have bad skill for reading C++ syntax.

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutor.

Comment: If like that can you please give me sime reference that relevant about my problem ?

Comment: @SufferProgrammer. Do not post images of code or error messages. Please copy and paste the actual text into your question.

Comment: show code in post

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to understand what your error is. The the "noneType" Object indicates that the Object you are trying yo use, does not exists yet.

The line of code that gives the cellWidget to your variable returns None. And one line later you use the `.text()` on a "noneType" object.

That means you do not use the `self.tableWidget.cellWidget(data,1)` correctly.

Here are some examples of QTableWidget and QTableWidget.cellWidget:
http://nullege.com/codes/search/PyQt4.Qt.QTableWidget.cellWidget